# How to enable personal run on all teamcity configurations

Tags: teamcity

Few of my team city configurations don't have an option to run a "personal run" while few others have.
I realized you need to be a project developer but i am a system administrator on the team city root project. So i should be able to personal run any project.
Dont understand how to get around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since TeamCity 9.1, you can restrict running personal builds by unchecking the allow triggering personal builds option (on by default).

Checkbox is located in **Build Configuration Settings** → **General Settings** tab/section. It is advanced option, so you might need to click "Show advanced options" pseudo-link to observe "Build options" section, where checkbox is.

Comment: @nimish was the answer helpful or your problem is of different kind?

Comment: yes the answer was helpful. Thank you so much. :) Sorry i am not as frequent as earlier.